# tomcat - Why doesn't directory level up work for images?

Tags: html, eclipse, tomcat

I am using Eclipse and Apache Tomcat, I have created a **dynamic web project** called SampleTest in the following path-:

```
G:\eclipse_workspace\SampleTest
```

Inside the SampleTest directory there are the following folders-:

```
.settings
build
imgs
src
WebContent
.classpath
.project
```

I have created the `imgs` folder from within Eclipse, the other folders where put there by the IDE.

The `imgs` folder will contain images that will be used by the application. I have a simple `<img>` tag in my index.html(it is located in the `WebContent` directory) as follows-:

```
<img alt="" src="../imgs/img.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

As you can see I have specifically instructed the web server to "go up" a directory from `WebContent` so that it may find the `imgs` folder.

This doesn't work. When I run the project in Eclipse no image is displayed. But if I keep the `imgs` inside the `WebContent` folder and use `/imgs/img.jpg` instead everything works fine.

Why can't Tomcat just go up a directory ? Is it not allowed to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't Tomcat just go up a directory ? Is it not allowed to ?

Correct, in that there is a security restriction designed to prevent attackers from copying your entire filesystem. But, that specific images folder isn't deployed instead everything is served relative to `WebContent` (making it the "root"), thus you can't go up a directory (that would be "above" the root *and* the imgs folder isn't part of the web deployment when you don't place it under WebContent).

Comment: So if I wanted to keep `imgs` folder above the `WebContent` directory what would I have to do ? I have tried adding `imgs` folder to the **Deployment Assembly** in Eclipse but it doesn't work.

Comment: In general, you can't and don't. Instead you put it in the `WebContent` folder. The path `/../` is going to be `/` when your environment evaluates the URL because you can't go up a folder from the root. Which direction is North when you stand on the North pole?

Comment: So there is absolutely no way to deploy something that is placed outside the WebContent directory ? Yes it works fine when I put it inside WebContent.

Comment: You could (theoretically) deploy it as another application at a different URL, or use a reverse proxy server and/or rewrite URL(s) but that's really not within the context of a single eclipse dynamic web-app (it's the kind of thing you do in deployment, not development).